# Saving page content using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium to gather data on a web portal.The problem here is the data is in XML format but the URL extension is not .xml and it is displayed as .aspx since it is a dot net website.Now using selenium I can get the page source by using `driver.getPageSource()`

But it gives me the format in HTML.Separating the XML here using HTML is really a pain and I have tried many options such as JSoup, but it seems like there is too much parsing to be done.

Is there any other way to make selenium manipulate the browser.I can see that File-Save as gives me an option to save the web page in xml format.How to do this in selenium?Are there any other API's that can help me out here.

Edit : My browser here is Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this ?

```
String pageSource=driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
```

see this **pageSource** content If it is giving only XML content you can write it to file using file operations.

Comment: Its not working.No content is showing up on the string.Thanks for the input though,ill try with some other elements and get back.

Comment: What is the problem? If that is html page It will content of that page without html tags. Can you post your URL here.

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem,there is no content getting stored in the string.Sorry there are some restrictions, I cannot post the URL here.

Comment: IT is ok. Just try with some other tag name, locator to get the content of that particular tag.

Comment: Done with it.It was actually an issue on the application side.Thanks for the idea :)